# Stop a function from writing to stdout

Tags: python, opencv, stdout

I have this line in my code:

```
writer = cv.CreateVideoWriter('video.avi', cv.CV_FOURCC('X','V','I','D'), 30 ,(480,800), 1)
```

Which outputs to console this:

```
Output #0, avi, to 'video.avi':
Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 480x800, q=2-31, 24576 kb/s, 90k tbn, 30 tbc
```

I want to stop it from printing anything to stdout, but keep the possibility to output by myself something further in the code. How can I achieve this?

I tried this, but it didn't worked.

```
class NullStream:
    def write(self, text):
        pass

sys.stdout = NullStream()
sys.stderr = NullStream()

print "hello" #This doesn't outputs

#This function still outputs to console:
writer = cv.CreateVideoWriter('video.avi', cv.CV_FOURCC('X','V','I','D'), 30 ,(480,800), 1)

sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not OpenCV that outputs this info. It's FFMPEG (which is called by OpenCV).

You can recompile FFMPEG to disable these debugs.

Comment: Is there a way to set the verbosity of ffmpeg without recompiling it?

Comment: Only if you are using the cmd-line tool: `ffmpeg -loglevel 0` , which is not what OpenCV does behind the curtains. Short answer: I don't know any other method besides recompiling.

Answer (score 2):

```
import os
import sys
saved_stdout, saved_stderr = sys.stdout, sys.stderr
sys.stdout = sys.stderr = open(os.devnull, "w")
writer = cv.CreateVideoWriter('video.avi', cv.CV_FOURCC('X','V','I','D'), 30 ,(480,800), 1)
sys.stdout, sys.stderr = saved_stdout, saved_stderr
print 'Now this will print to stdout'
```

Demo:

```
>>> import os
>>> import sys
>>> saved_stdout, saved_stderr = sys.stdout, sys.stderr
>>> sys.stdout = sys.stderr = open(os.devnull, "w")
>>> print 'hello world'                     # no output
>>> sys.stderr.write('Invisible Error!\n')  # no ouput
>>> sys.stdout, sys.stderr = saved_stdout, saved_stderr
>>> print 'goodbye world'                   
goodbye world
>>> sys.stderr.write('Error!\n')
Error!
```

Comment: Tested it, it's still outputs the same thing.

Comment: By the way, is there an advantage of using the saved_stdout = sys.stdout, instead of sys.__stdout__ ?

Comment: See demo edit. Seems to work for me. I've used this approach a lot. I don't know the answer to the `sys.__stdout__` question.

Comment: Yes, it works for a simple print, but for unknown reason it doesn't work for this openCV function, do you have any ideas why it can still output to stdout?