# Python 3.4 Writing to File is Writing to Console?

Tags: file-io, python-3.4

Why am I getting output on my console when writing to file? I don't recall this ever happening before...

```
outfile= open("C:\\Data\\testout.txt", 'w')
outfile.write("something")
outfile.write("something else")
```

output:

```
9
14
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python versions > `3.0`, the `write` method returns the number of bytes written.

http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

Comment: I see... Is there a way I can STOP it from doing that??

Comment: this should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10321671/stop-a-function-from-writing-to-stdout